# Construct unordered_map with a value_type of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr, unordered-map

This snippet of code doesn't seem to work because the unique pointer gets stored into a pair object and then is attempted to be copied from it. Can this be avoided?

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<int>> _map {
    {"hello", std::make_unique<int>(7)}
};
```

A full code example and compilation error can be seen here http://cpp.sh/7uc3a

Comment: You can use [emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace)

Comment: That seems like it could work but I'm looking for a way to do this in the initialization step. I'm hoping to make my _map variable const. I could use an "immediately invoked lambda expression" or something which itself using emplace but that's not quite as ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately, the elements of a `std::initializer_list<E>` are `const`.

Comment: This is the same issue with `std::vector`, you have to `emplace` if your elements are not copy-constructible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, by not using list-initialization.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<int>> _map;
_map.insert({"hello", std::make_unique<int>(7)});
```

---

`std::unordered_map` needs to call either the copy or move constructor in order to store any keys and values in its internal buffer. In the case of `std::unique_ptr`, the copy constructor is deleted, since making a copy of a `std::unique_ptr` would make it, well, not unique at all. That leaves only the move constructor.
The problem is with how you're initializing your map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<int>> _map {
    {"hello", std::make_unique<int>(7)}
};
```

You're initializing your map's values using a `std::initializer_list`.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type std::initializer_list is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type **const T**.

Effectively, all of the values in your initializer list are const. That means the move constructor on your `std::unique_ptr` can't be called, since moving an object generally requires modifying the original instance. Since the `std::unique_ptr` can't be moved, the compiler falls back on the copy constructor, which is why it ends up complaining that the copy constructor is deleted.

The snippet I posted works because `insert` accepts a non-const `std::pair`, which means that the `std::unique_ptr` is non-const, and can have its move constructor called.

Comment: Yeah, that's a limitation.