# How do I convert this example to use unique_ptr instead of the generic pointer?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

Here's the code. I've added a comment to identify the location where I would like the modification (if possible) to be made. Essentially, to avoid the mistakes while using raw pointers, I felt it would be more ideal to use smart pointers here. Do let me know what you think would the ideal approach be!

```
class Airline {
    public:
        virtual double TicketCost(double miles, string class_name) = 0;
    protected:
        double OperatingCost(double miles, string class_name);
};

double Airline::OperatingCost(double miles, string class_name){
        return 50 + 0.25*miles;
}

class Delta : public Airline {
    public:
        double TicketCost(double miles, string class_name) override{
            return 1.0*miles + OperatingCost(miles, class_name);
        }
};

class Southwest : public Airline {
    public:
        double TicketCost(double miles, string class_name) override{
            if(class_name=="Economy"){
                return 0.5*miles + 50;
            }
            else{
                return 150.0;
            }
        }
};

// How to modify this to use unique_ptr?
unordered_map<string, Airline* > airline_map{
    {"Delta", new Delta},
    {"Southwest", new Southwest}
};

vector<vector<string>> input{
    {"Delta", "100.0", "Economy"},
    {"Southwest", "150.0", "Business"}
};

int main()
{
    for(const auto& vec_string: input){
        const string& airline_name = vec_string[0];
        const double miles = stod(vec_string[1]);
        const string& class_name = vec_string[2];
        // These lines would also have to be modified
        auto* airline_ptr = airline_map[airline_name];
        cout<<airline_ptr->TicketCost(miles, class_name)<<endl;
        delete airline_ptr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting stuck on a particular compilation or runtime error? Unique pointers are a fine idea here.

Comment: I think the first step here would be understand how `unique_ptr` works. It's not as simple as modifying the declaration where the comment is. There's much more to this. For example, the whole purpose of using `unique_ptr` is for it to do the `delete` for you. So that `delete` goes bye-bye. Next: unique_ptr is not copyable. Therefore,  you can't just copy some unique_ptr out of the map, like that, in `main()`. Are you familiar with these basic fundamentals of unique_ptr?

Comment: What do you want done with the now-dangling pointer in `airline_map` after the object it was pointing at is obliterated with `delete airline_ptr;` or its replacement?

Comment: `unique_ptr` and list initialization is a pain in the <expletive deleted> because the contents of an `initializer_list` are `const`. I figured someone had a better explanation of the problem than me and I was right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072896/4581301 . If this is what you ran into let us know and we'll close as a dupe.

Comment: This code effectively runs as expected. I wanted to know if we can use unique_ptr here as smart pointers are better to use than raw pointers @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Like @user4581301 said, the fact that initializer_list is const makes it impossible for us to use move constructors, and effectively unique_ptrs... Best way is to insert or emplace it.

Comment: Yes, unique_ptr can be used here; but as I explained, the first step towards this goal is to actually learn how `unique_ptr` works, and its core fundamental principles. It's not as simple as changing the declaration and expecting everything else to work automatically. C++ is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
// How to modify this to use unique_ptr?
unordered_map<string, Airline* > airline_map{
    {"Delta", new Delta},
    {"Southwest", new Southwest}
};
```

It is straightforward:

```
unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<Airline> > airline_map{
    {"Delta", make_unique<Delta>()},
    {"Southwest", make_unique<Southwest>()}
};
```

(note: `unique_ptr` is `std::unique_ptr` and `make_unique` is `std::make_unique`. I assume you wrote `using namespace std;` somewhere)

```
// These lines would also have to be modified
auto* airline_ptr = airline_map[airline_name];
cout<<airline_ptr->TicketCost(miles, class_name)<<endl;
delete airline_ptr;
```

Yes they would. Do you really want to delete the airline here or leave it alone?

Right now, your code deletes the airline, but the pointer is still in airline_map pointing to the empty space where the airline used to be, and if you accidentally used it again, you could have a problem. With unique_ptr you are *forced* to decide what to do with this pointer.

Option 1: leave the airline alone and don't delete it. You can only have one unique_ptr, and it has to stay in the map if we want it to stay in the map, so we can access the airline like this:

```
// .get() gets a normal pointer and leaves the unique_ptr alone
auto* airline_ptr = airline_map[airline_name].get();
cout<<airline_ptr->TicketCost(miles, class_name)<<endl;
```

Option 1b:

```
// the unique_ptr stays alone and airline_ptr is a reference to the unique_ptr
auto& airline_ptr = airline_map[airline_name];
cout<<airline_ptr->TicketCost(miles, class_name)<<endl;
```

Option 2: take the pointer out of the map and delete it, leaving the airline name still in the map, but with a null pointer. Doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but I include it here so you can how unique_ptr works:

```
// Move the unique_ptr out of the map, leaving a null pointer behind in the map
// airline_ptr is a unique_ptr
auto airline_ptr = move(airline_map[airline_name]); // std::move
cout<<airline_ptr->TicketCost(miles, class_name)<<endl;
// when airline_ptr goes out of scope the airline is deleted
```

Option 3 is to delete the airline from the map. Maps are annoying; there are lots of ways you could erase a thing from a map. I'll let you pick your favourite way.